# Error creating ubuntu 16 container under arch

Tags: ubuntu-16.04, x86-64, archlinux, lxc, linux-containers

I am trying to install a Ubuntu container on Archlinux using LXC. I am following this guide:https://gist.github.com/manoj23/8a35849697945896cdaef77927c695a7

After I run this command:

```
lxc-create --name=ubuntu-16 --template=ubuntu -- --release xenial  --arch amd64
```

I get the following error:

```
Bad template: ubuntu
Error creating container ubuntu-16
```

Why is this happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It says in the error. Bad template.

You can see that in the [current version of lxc](https://github.com/lxc/lxc/tree/master/templates) there is no ubuntu template. The gist is probably for [the previous version](https://github.com/lxc/lxc/tree/stable-2.1/templates).

The LXC documentation does not really have any clear examples of using their updated method. The Ubunu LXC documentation does though. https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/lxc.html

Comment: Thanks! That worked. But now I am getting: ssh: connect to host 192.168.122.2 port 22: Connection refused  when I run : ssh ubuntu@192.168.122.2