# Ubuntu container failed to start

Tags: lxc, linux-containers

I have a Ubuntu Xenial container with an amd64 architecture setup in my Arch Linux computer. The container works properly. However, when I tried to start the container a second time I got this error:

> The container failed to start.
>   To get more details, run the container in foreground mode.
>   Additional information can be obtained by setting the --logfile and --logpriority options.

What could have caused that?

Got this after running with -F, --logfile and --logpriority options.

> lxc-start: ubuntu: network.c: lxc_ovs_attach_bridge: 1893 Failed to
>   attach "virbr0" to openvswitch bridge "veth3PI00B": lxc-start: ubuntu:
>   utils.c: run_command: 2280 failed to exec command
>
> lxc-start: ubuntu: network.c: instantiate_veth: 198 Failed to attach
>   "veth3PI00B" to bridge "virbr0": Operation not permitted
>
> lxc-start: ubuntu: network.c: lxc_create_network_priv: 2452 Failed to
>   create network device
>
> lxc-start: ubuntu: start.c: lxc_spawn: 1579 Failed to create the
>   network
>
> lxc-start: ubuntu: start.c: __lxc_start: 1887 Failed to spawn
>   container "ubuntu"

Got this after running it without foreground mode:

> lxc-start: ubuntu: lxccontainer.c: wait_on_daemonized_start: 834
>   Received container state "STOPPING" instead of "RUNNING"

Comment: The container was created with guidance from this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51713879/error-creating-ubuntu-16-container-under-arch).

Answer (score 2):

I faced a similar issue, and it got resolved upon creating the bridge. Following command used to create a bridge:

```
sudo brctl addbr brs1s2
```

Where *"brs1s2"* is the bridge-name in my case.